# Mysql INTERSECT not working

Tags: mysql

I have multi select query and I need intersect the result
Query:

```
select pro_id from product_extra_data where type_filed_id='1' and value like '%Intel Xeon%' 
intersect
select pro_id from product_extra_data where type_filed_id='3' and value like '%15%' 
intersect   
select pro_id from product_extra_data where type_filed_id='49' and value like '%8GB%' 
intersect 
select pro_id from product_extra_data where type_filed_id='50' and value like '%460W%' 
intersect
select pro_id from product_extra_data where type_filed_id='47' and value like '%1%' 
intersect 
select pro_id from product_extra_data where type_filed_id='51' and value like '%5U%'
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Does the query produce an error? The wrong result?

Comment: An inner join would do exactly what you are looking for would it not? Where pro_id == pro_id, then just select one column, although im not sure how efficient it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support intersect, but on this particular context you can obtain the same result with a group by query like this:

```
select
  pro_id
from
  product_extra_data
where
  (type_filed_id='1' and value like '%Intel Xeon%')
  or
  (type_filed_id='3' and value like '%15%')
  or
  (type_filed_id='49' and value like '%8GB%')
  or
  (type_filed_id='50' and value like '%460W%')
  or
  (type_filed_id='47' and value like '%1%')
  or
  (type_filed_id='51' and value like '%5U%')
group by
  pro_id
having
  count(distinct type_filed_id)=6
```